# Do firebase.User objects contain sensitive data that shouldn't be shared with other users?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My scenario is that I have a "Room" object and am tracking a list of users who are in the room. If I store the users as a list of firebase.User objects, this exposes those objects to anyone with access to the room.

Does this expose any sensitive data? I could filter this data and only include uid, displayName and photoURL in the DB.

Comment: Only you know this for sure.  You'll have to audit the actual data that you're writing, and determine for yourself if any of it is "sensitive", by whatever criteria you determine.  Since you're not showing exactly what you're actually writing, we can't even make a guess as to whether or not some item of data is sensitive.  If you have any concerns at all you should probably just limit the data to what you know to be OK.

Comment: I'm literally asking about https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User. Concerned about providerData etc

Answer (score 1):

As long as your "users" collection has [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) preventing users from viewing other user's sensitive data it is fine to store an object containing a small amount of identifying information (uid, displayName and photoURL) in a public document like a "room."

Comment: Thanks for that. So I'm gathering from your answer that you would not store entire firebase.User objects in the DB, but only "a small amount of identifying information".

Comment: I don't have an app with specific security requirements to meet, so I don't have an opinion about that.  It's all about defining and meeting requirements.  Everything outside of that is opinion, and people can disagree wildly about that.